# add off topic tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

:

> this may be a duplicate question.

:

there should be an `off topic` tag for questions that may be valuable to mac users, but aren't directly related to Apple

> an example may be something related to file types: "Why should I use this file type", or "my external display wont connect", or "google chrome wont open on any device". Something that could involve apple, but doesn't.

etc..

> this may be a bad example, but it may be useful

Comment: This is so meta, I kind of like it. It goes against what a tag should be, but it might be useful. What of people edit a closed question to add this and that burns the one edit review it gets? I think we need to get that changed so that when the OP edits the question, it asks if this edit is intended to trigger a review.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure I see a benefit here. If a question is off-topic we put it on hold to give the OP the opportunity to revise it, and close it if they don’t (or the scope of the question doesn’t allow it). So a question is either on-topic and properly tagged, or closed (and tags not really important any longer).

Comment: I'm in complete agreement with this; I can't see any benefit to having this tag.  If it's for statistical analysis, there's already mechanisms in place to to find questions that were closed/migrated/deleted for all the various reasons.